# Cannot create EmbeddedField in djongo getting this error django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, djongo

hey people I'm new to djongo and was practicing it's usage when i keep getting this error

File "D:\python\django Rest webs\tms-REST API\BACKEND\bckend\students\models.py", line 6, in 
    class student(models.Model):
  File "D:\python\django Rest webs\tms-REST API\BACKEND\bckend\students\models.py", line 7, in student
    pass_details=models.EmbeddedField(model_container=pass_details, null=True)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 225, in **init**
    super().**init**(model_container, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 87, in **init**
    self._validate_container()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 91, in _validate_container
    for field in self.model_container._meta.get_fields():
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 734, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(include_parents=include_parents, include_hidden=include_hidden)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 794, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in **get**
    res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 707, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 678, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 178, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 140, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

MY Code looks like so

```
from djongo import models
class pass_details(models.Model):
    pass_no=models.CharField( max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
class student(models.Model):
    pass_details=models.EmbeddedField(model_container=pass_details, null=True)
    usn=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are loading your models in:`pass_details=models.EmbeddedField(model_container=pass_details, null=True)`
It seems to me that the null = True is preventing you to load your model.
You can have a look again on the documentation on how to specify the parameters here: https://djongo.readthedocs.io/docs/embedded-model-field/

Comment: I copy pasted the same code and still got  the same error

Comment: @HarshithYadav were you able to resolve this? I am having the same issue with djongo==1.3.2. I downgraded to 1.3.1 and it worked ok.